# any universal non serif font in normal and bold variant

Tags: css, fonts

```
.title{
font-family:'Arial Bold';
}
```

I thought there will not be a problem with `Arial` font but...

`Arial Bold` - doesn't exists on my Chrome, or Windows 7.

Arial Black is too heavy.

Is there any (non serif) font I can be sure it exists on any platform, any browser as `normal` and `bold` variant?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser is right: *Arial Bold* does not exist as a font family of its own. Arial is one of the most commonly available font families among operating systems. According to [this source](http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html):

> Helvetica is the granddaddy here, but Arial is more common on modern OS's.

What you're missing here is that you're trying to specify the font weight as part of the font family. What you need right here is [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).
Font family *Arial Bold* does not exist, as your browser says.

The `font-family` should only take `Arial` in your case. To control whether you want your font to be bold or regular, or italic, or underlined, you have to use different properties with their respective values in CSS.

`font-weight` takes the following values among others: `regular`, `bold`. So in order to use Arial, bold, your CSS would look like this:

```
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-weight: regular; // I prefer to use numeric values myself
```

Comment: how to get `Arial Bold`, pls

Comment: @qadenza there is no such font family as `Arial Bold`. `Arial` is the font family, `bold` is the weight. Combining the two as I wrote in the answer will get your bold Arial. It's not really fair to downvote my answer without even reading it to the end.

Comment: oh, I see, thansk. seems that's special for `arial` other fonts have with `bold` after font name.

Comment: @qadenza it depends on your system. After all, every browser attempts to load font files from your system if you don't use any external services. But since you probably want your site to look the same on as many devices as possible, you need to rely on a font that's commonly available (again, unless you use an external service), so Arial is one of the safest to use for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using @import to import a font from a server. If you are open to do that, this should be a good solution to what you are trying to do.

See this article for a good reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/#article-header-id-5